# Does the Chinese song have any further relevance?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

The [*Daredevil*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322312/) episode "World on Fire" (S01E05) sees one of Madame Gao's couriers deliver a package to Vladimir's men. While he sits in the car and the Russians get inside he sings some Chinese song, until the situation escalates due to Daredevil's intervention and the courier inadvertently gets shot.

Now the situation with madame Gao's couriers and helpers has always been interesting due to the fact that they are actually all blind. I wonder **if that Chinese song has any further relevance** or if it's just some random distraction to support the mood of the scene. So is that some common Chinese folk song and do its lyrics or meaning relate to that situation and its themes in any way?

Comment: The song is [Kangding Love Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangding_Qingge), which is a traditional folk song from Kangding China.  The translation is at the link.  Maybe because it has something to do with "moonlight", or because it is slightly defiant?  It is nice to see the creators respect languages and cultures in that show, more than just giving people inscrutable accents?

Answer (score 3):

It's a folk love song in China. Mainly about a village girl loves a village boy and how great a couple they are. I don't think there is any deeper meaning of it.

Comment: Do you have any sources about the song to back this up, perhaps a recording of it?